# How can I solve my RAID installation problems?

Tags: 12.10, server, intel, raid

Trying to install Ubuntu Server 12.10 64-bit (also tried 12.04.1 64-bit LTS) with a RAID5 array but machine does not boot grub (I get the black screen with the blinking cursor), and I have tried

Hardware:

- Four 2TB SATA drives (no hardware RAID)
- Intel Server Board S1200BT w/Xeon E3 1200
- 8GB RAM

I have tried numerous resources, and the Advanced Installation Docs from Ubuntu (which I followed) did not work as I expected.

Here are a few of the ways I partitioned and created SoftwareRAID for install, I used the Manual partitioning tool in the Ubuntu Server setup:

1. Raid5 Device #0: 9GB SWAP, Raid5 Device #1: ~6TB ext4 /
2. Raid1 Device #0: 1GB ext4 /boot, Raid5 Device #1: 9GB SWAP, Raid5 Device #2 ~6TB /

I have also tried putting /boot with the 'bootable flag = on' on drive 0, then using the setup listed in #1 above.

I can't seem to find anything relevant in the BIOS that might help this either, there are no settings or information regarding RAID.

Can anyone provide assistance? I am a novice at RAID and intermediate with Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

I set up the following partitions:

1. Disk0: 250MB EFIboot, bootable = on
2. RAID5 Swap of: Disk0 3.0GB, Disk1 3.0GB, Disk2 3.0GB, Disk3 3.0GB
3. RAID5 /ext4 of remaining space on each drive